# IE7 Not Floating List Elements in Navbar, When No Height is Specified

Tags: html, floating

I made a navbar and it works perfectly in all browsers except IE7. Below is a link to an example. Here is a quick explanation of what Im trying to accomplish. The navbar is wrapped in a `ul` and floated each list item to the left this works perfectly in all browsers except IE7 in which case each `li` item is on its own line and all but the first one is hidden, because the `ul` has a set height. I tried everything I could think of (even changing display modes) and nothing worked> I know it might be easier to use specific widths but I just think that there has got to be something simpler. Thanks

Check out the sample below:
http://jsfiddle.net/XV9nQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/moeishaa/W43w5/

I removed `float:left` and the `height` from the `ul`. Added a new css class `clearfix` to the `ul`. When you are floating things, add the `clearfix` class to the parent and you should be set. You dont need to specify a height

Comment: wow thanks a lot this worked!! Quick question how is this clearfix different than just using clear:both in an empty paragraph tag at the right before the parent closing tag

Comment: that is the other way. few years ago I was doing it that way but this way is alot cleaner and works on anything I have tried. I think it is much uglier to add an empty element before the parent closing. :-) glad this helped

Comment: I agree it is pretty damn ugly gonna try this out thanks again

Comment: not being a point whore, but if this is the correct answer can you mark it as answered? since some other people will most likely end up here by doing a google search and it helps to know there was answer :-)

Comment: yeah I just checked it does that close the question?